# How can you remove or add JS to the theme based on criteria?

Tags: javascript

I tried adding the code to `template/page/html/head.phtml`

```
if (Mage::helper('mobiledetect')->isMobile()){
  $this->addItem('js', 'js/mobile_jsscript.js');
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->removeItem('js', 'js/normal_js_script.js');
}
```

Is this the correct way to add and remove js based on criteria?

Comment: which functionality is not wotking? mobile  redirection or js add

Comment: @AmitBera The Adding of JS is not working, not sure if it is in the correct place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeItem()` function,is working when we have add js file using `addItem()`

**through  xml code :**

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/normal_js_script.js</name></action>
```

**or php code:**

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_js', 'js/normal_js_script.js');
```

Or,it may be issue with params issue in function `removeItem($type,$filepath)`

`skin_js` instead of  `js`

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->removeItem('skin_js', 'js/normal_js_script.js');
```

Remove Item from HEAD entity

**Just like:**

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether above function returns correct results..but you can do using jquery also....refer to below link and download required script like jquery  or php and replace your if condition correspoding to your downloaded script.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/